# Recursive function using rest operator not returning in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, arguments

Imagine you want to write a recursive function that takes an accumulator and any number of ints as arguments, and you want to return the accumulator once all arguments have been summed. I am trying to express that as follows:

```
function f(x, ...y) {
  if (!y.length) {
    return x;
  } 
  else {
    x += y.shift();
    f(x, ...y);
  }
}

f(0,2,4,7,8,4)
```

If you add a `console.log(x)` to the first `if` statement, you will see the correct answer, but when you run the function, it returns `undefined`, so where in the recursive chain is it getting lost? I believe my base case for this recursive function is right but I'd like some insight.

Comment: It's strange – I see almost one question per day about simple recursive functions where the answer is *"you're missing a `return` before the recursive call"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the function to itself:

```
return f(x, ...y);
```

```js
function f(x, ...y) {
  if (!y.length) {
    return x;
  } else {
    x += y.shift();
    return f(x, ...y);
  }
}

console.log(f(0, 2, 4, 7, 8, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return from `else`.

```
function f(x, ...y) {
    if (!y.length) {
        return x;
    } else {
        x += y.shift();
        return f(x, ...y);
//      ^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

In your code, if `y.length !== 0` then you are in the `else` block, you call `f` that should return a value, but you do not return that value to whatever called `f`.